# Error message on looping "for" javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, onkeyup

I have a string from input that I need to transform to CAP on each first word using keyup.

here is the script:

```
$(".cap_first").on("keyup", function () {
    const string = $(this).val();
    const words = string.split(" ");

    for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        words[i] = words[i][0].toUpperCase() + words[i].substr(1).toLowerCase();
    }
    $(this).val(words.join(" "));
});
```

It return as what I need and work but on console show me this error:
"Uncaught TypeError: words[i][0] is undefined"

I understand a rule that if it work, then don't touch. But I feel something wrong if the console show an red

Thanks

I have tried to change the const name but still show the error

Comment: Did you read the error? Get in the habit of reading errors, don't ignore them.

Comment: my mistake, it should work... it probably means that `word` is empty (cannot be found).  Since we do not know what the HTML looks like, we can't tell what value it might hold after `const string = $(this).val();`

Comment: @blurfus not that it can't be found. It means it's `""` so `""[0]` is `undefined`. Depends on what `string` is before it's split. E.g., `"".split(" ")` or `" ".split(" ")` or `"a  b".split(" ")` (note two spaces) can yield empty strings.

Comment: @blurfus Yes it is work find, and return as what I want. Just showing the error on console. Just found the answer, It's because on whitespace input upon keyup.

Comment: @AndyRay Thank you for your suggestion and I did. But as I am not the native English. It can be challenging.

Answer (score 0):

Most cases something like `Uncaught TypeError: words[i][0] is undefined` is caused when words[i] is of size 0, i.e. empty string.

In your case if the user enters a a string with two consecutive whitespace, the split array will have one item of length 0. And since the length is zero you will get the above error when trying to access index 0.

```
let str = "2  spaces";
let words = str.split(" ");  // ['2', '', 'spaces']
```

Comment: Thank you Niki, I Understood the logic. I have tried. If typing on input without whitespace, the console show no error.

Answer (score 0):

Why work manually when you have css for this job.

```css
/*p {text-transform: capitalize;}*/
 p {
            text-transform: lowercase;
        }
   
    p::first-letter {
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }
```

```html
<p>error message on Looping "for" Javascript</p>
```

Comment: This approach is ok if you only want to display the value like that - btw, you can just use `capitalize` (since it's a one word value).  However, this is not helpful if you actually want to send the modified value to some other place (like submitting it in a form to a backend service)